# How to pass std::barrier to a thread function with an on_completion function which takes an input

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, synchronization

I'm trying to implement a C++ program which has a thread function `threadfn` which makes use of a barrier for synchronisation purposes. I initialised the barrier object in the caller-function, and then passed it to the thread function by following the answer in this question: [How to pass an std::barrier with a lambda completion function to a named function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75197002/how-to-pass-an-stdbarrier-with-a-lambda-completion-function-to-a-named-functio)

However, in this question the on_completion function does not take any input arguments. I could not find a way to modify this to take another input argument, like the Data object in my code below

This is the simplified version of my code:

```
void thread_function(Data& data, std::barrier<void(*)(void) noexcept>& bar) {
    ...
    bar.arrive_and_wait()
    ...
}

int main() {
    std::barrier<void(*)(void) noexcept> barrier(thread_count, []() noexcept {std::cout << "barrier reached";});

}
```

Ideally I would like to change the on_complete function to something like:

```
std::barrier<void(*)(Data&) noexcept> barrier(thread_count, [&data]() noexcept {// update Data object here});
```

But I couldn't find a way how to fully link this to the thread function and also how will the on_complete function have an access to the Data object all the time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::function`, below is full example:

https://godbolt.org/z/6Ev86G47E

```
struct Data {};
void thread_function(Data& data, std::barrier<std::function<void()>>& bar) {
    bar.arrive_and_wait();
 }

int main() {
    int thread_count = 10;
    Data d;
    std::barrier<std::function<void()>> barrier(thread_count, [&d]() noexcept 
     {std::cout << "barrier reached";});


    std::vector<std::thread> ts;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < thread_count; ++i) 
        ts.emplace_back(thread_function, std::ref(d), std::ref(barrier));
    for (auto& t : ts)
        t.join();
}
```